# Reliable infrastructure for website php and mysql with two servers - the right way?

Tags: php, mysql, replication, scalability, lamp

I am not really sure if I can describe the situation in a couple of words.
Right now we have a website built on top of traditional LAMP stack. 
The client wants to build "reliable infrastructure".

Right now we have two separate Linux machines with two MySQL and application instances.
Databases are connected via "master-master" replication. Also some kind of "load balancing" was implemented: every new request is sent to the next server via "round robin.

This scheme is not really reliable, because we already had problems with it. 
For example, user have session with the first server and does not have session with other due to slow replication process.
Another problem is lack of scalability.

The client has to use anti-DDOS service (http://qrator.net/en/), so we cannot use sticky sessions.

What are possible solutions?

Thank you for your help.